# How to get display width of a string from Linux command line?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, svg, awk, fonts

I am working on an AWK script that processes a text file line by line, formats them and stuffs them into an SVG file text field. The SVG takes care of text wrapping automatically, but I want to predict where each line will wrap. (I need some characters to repeat and extend close to the end of the line). I know the exact font, font size, and width of the text field.

Is there a standard utility in Linux or easily available in Ubuntu that will give a width in pixels or inches given a string, font, and font size?

For example:

```
get-width 'Nimbus Sans L' 18 "test string"
returns "x pixels"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the ghostscript interpreter, assuming you have that and the fonts are set up correctly.

Here is the possibly mysterious incantation:

```
gs -dQUIET -sDEVICE=nullpage 2>/dev/null - \
   <<<'18 /NimbusSanL-Regu   findfont exch scalefont setfont
      (test string)          stringwidth pop =='
```

Using `-dQUIET` suppresses warnings about font substitution, which is probably not a good idea until you have some idea about how to name the fonts you're looking for.

`ghostscript` is not a layout engine, and you may find the measurement doesn't work with complicated bidirectional text, combining characters, or East Asian languages. (I tested it with a little Arabic, and it was OK, but no guarantees.) It does not kern, so it will normally produce measurements a little larger than a good layout engine, and possibly a lot larger if the font positions diacritics using kerning.

Finally, if your text includes unbalanced parentheses or backslashes, you'll need to escape them. I use the following:

```
"$(sed 's/[()\\]/\\&/g' <<<"$text")"
```

That's because Postscript strings are enclosed in `(...)` -- `(test string)` -- and are allowed to include balanced parentheses. Unbalanced parentheses will usually generate a syntax error, unless they are backslash-escaped.

Comment: a note about using this for SVG/Inkscape. Inkscape uses 90 DPI, so their 'points' don't equal regular 72 DPI 'points'. 18/90=0.2,0.2*72=14.4. Use 14.4 size here if you want to match 18 points in Inkscape land. Also use 'stringwidth pop div 72 ==' to get the answer in inches.

Comment: @kcghost: Using size 18 for gs is fine if you want to match Inkscape's size 18 font (which is 18/90 of an inch), which is why it actually produces comparable values to Inkscape (see Cyrus's answer and OP's comment). In other words, everything is scaled by the same amount. To convert to inches you need to divide by DPI.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to [inkscape](/questions/tagged/inkscape):

```
FONT="Nimbus Sans L"
SIZE=18
STRING="test string"
inkscape --without-gui --query-id=id1 -W <(echo '<svg><text id="id1" style="font-size:'$SIZE'px;font-family:'$FONT';">'$STRING'</text></svg>') 2>/dev/null
```

Output (e.g.):

```
76.577344
```

Comment: I had a hard time choosing an 'accepted answer'. This is a very useful answer especially as I am already using Inkscape in my script. For SVG purposes, this gives a more accurate width than ghostscript (gs gives 78.0234375). But I need to run in a loop. The Inkscape solution takes about 0.182 seconds on my machine, ghostscript takes about 0.059 seconds.